# Loading a module from the current directory in racket

Tags: racket

I have a file `euler.rkt` in my current working directory.
How do I load it as a module?

```
-> (require euler)
; readline-input:20:9: euler: standard-module-name-resolver: collection not
;   found: "euler" in any of: (#<path:/home/ben/.racket/5.2.1/collects>
;   #<path:/home/ben/racket/collects>) in: euler [,bt for context]
->
```

Should I add my directory to collects? 
If so, what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
(require "euler.rkt")
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to just using the path, as @soegaard mentions, you can also use [`raco link`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/link.html?q=link) to set up a collection for your file.